# ResourceBundleMessageSource Error

Tags: spring, resourcebundle

Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.spring")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean("msg")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:locales/locales");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

File locales.properties locate in src/main/resources/locales
But when I call in xhtml:

```
  ${msg.Welcome}
```

And start page, return error:

```
/index.xhtml: The class 'org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource' does not have the property 'Welcome'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve value and display like below on jsp.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<spring:message code="msg.Welcome"/>
```

and your locales.properties file should have entry like below

```
msg.Welcome= Welcome...!!!
```

For JSF just remove the `taglib` with `html xmlns` tag and try like below

```
<html   xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
<spring:message code="msg.Welcome"/>
```

Comment: Сan not be used on the jsf page directive taglib, only on a jsp pages.